# Server not using the latest kernel installed

Tags: linux, rhel, kernel, boot

I am running RHEL 7.3

I updated the `/boot` configuration based on one of the answers from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/82204/resizing-the-boot-partition) (Relocate /boot to the root partition).
After that, I upgraded the kernel from `kernel-3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64` to kernel-`3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64`.

It is installed as per below:

```
[root@qradar-hardened user]# rpm -qa | grep kernel
kernel-3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
kernel-tools-3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
[root@qradar-hardened user]#
```

However, after reboot, this change is not reflected.

```
[root@qradar-hardened user]# uname -r
3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
[root@qradar-hardened user]#
```

I did the same without making changes to `/boot` and it works. So I think it has something to do with changing that.

I followed [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1605183) guide and changed the boot order to use this new kernel, but still does not work.

Just need to make sure how can I make this to use the latest kernel.

Comment: When installing a new kernel with `rpm` it will not automatically be configured. You need to edit the `/boot/grub/grub.conf` directory to reflect which kernel you want to use. Check this guide out: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s1-kernel-boot-loader

Comment: i installed it using yum. And as mentioned, if I dont make changes in /boot, it works

Answer (score 0):

The guide you mentioned states that following command to be executed:

```
grub2-set-default 1
```

However, looking at the output of the previous command:

```
awk -F\' '$1=="menuentry " {print $2}' /etc/grub2.cfg
```

Results in:

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64) 7.3 (Maipo)
>   <-- Entry 0
>
> Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64) 7.3 (Maipo)
>   <-- Entry 1

By setting the default kernel to entry 1 will load the older kernel, so instead of using

```
grub2-set-default 1
```

Use:

```
grub2-set-default 0
```

Comment: I made these changes as per need already. It does not work

Comment: It would have been helpful if that was mentioned in your initial post.

Comment: its added in the post